# Does it make sense to use command pattern when your commands always need to run in a particular order?

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-pattern

If I have 5 commands A,B,C,D,E and they always need to run in that order. There is a good possibility that more commands would get added to that list. But they always need to be run in that order. Also on a failure the execution must stop. The next command is to be invoked only after previous one succeeds.

In a scenario such as above, does it make any sense to use command pattern?

Comment: That feels like it should be Commands in a Strategy pattern.

Comment: Well, put them in a list. A list is ordered.Why don't you try implementing something, and ask if you have a concrete problem? This is too vague.

Comment: In a typical command pattern, threads pick up items from the queue and execute them in parallel. I don't want them to execute in parallel. B should be executed only after A succeeds.

Comment: Then don't. Just use a loop, and execute one after the other.

Comment: In that case do I gain anything by applying command pattern? I know this is a general question that can be a little hard to answer, but I don't want to spend a week developing something and then realize I was going the wrong way.

Comment: ... If a pattern doesn't fit the situation ... Don't use it .. Or adapt it to suit your needs ..

Comment: Your "parallel" assertion is unfounded. My current application uses command objects to specify callbacks that should be executed when Webhooks are received on asynchronous job completion. Serialization (for delayed execution or undo) is a valuable feature.

Comment: What benefit do you expect from ordered Commands?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Though you'll likely want a queue storing the data needed by each each command to ensure proper ordering:

```
queue = (A, B, C, D, E)

def command(state):
  # ...

item = queue.shift()
command(item)  # Processes state 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

The nature of the problem implies a chain of processors. Good matches would be Chain of Responsibility and Intercepting Filter patterns.

The [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern is a design pattern consisting of command objects and a series of processing objects. Each processing object contains logic that defines the types of command objects that it can handle; the rest are passed to the next processing object in the chain. A mechanism also exists for adding new processing objects to the end of this chain.

In [Intercepting Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercepting_filter_pattern) (Java EE presentation tier pattern) the filters form a series of independent modules that can be chained together to execute a set of common processing steps before the page request is passed to the controller object.